# sql cursor insert result into a table

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I have created a cursor which iterates through all the databases and displays the 1 record per database.

I would like the records to be inserted into 1 table where I can view it. The query may change which is why I don't want to create the table structure for a specific query and insert it. I wanted to use the **"select into"** clause but that will fail on the second time the cursor runs

```
DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(100) 
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(200)
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM #DBNAME

OPEN database_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
     SELECT @Command = 'use [' + @DB_Name + '] Select '''+ @DB_Name + ''' ,'+

 --Enter query below
 '* from authentication where username like ''%clair@indicater%'' and password = ''Rohan2410'''

 --  print @Command
 EXEC sp_executesql @Command


 FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 
END

CLOSE database_cursor 
DEALLOCATE database_cursor
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. I get the part about looking at all the databases. But after that it makes no sense. You mention select into but that isn't in your code. And truly you don't need a cursor for this. You can leverage dynamic sql in a different way. If you can explain your desired output I will show you what I am talking about.

Comment: You shouldn't need the 'Use db' statement either. Just qualify the tablename with the dbname.dbo.tablename syntax.

Comment: Don't Use **"select into"** clause in your case , "select into" clause is created a new table automatically, so in the next time the query will be failed becouse the table name that engine wanna create it is already exist.  

Go to another approach via inserting into temp table then after ending of cursor insert the data from temp table to new table via SELECT INTO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better use INSERT INTO ... instead of SELECT INTO, something like this:

```
DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(100) 
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(200)
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM #DBNAME

OPEN database_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN

     SELECT @Command = 'use [' + @DB_Name + '] 

     IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..##output'') IS NULL
         BEGIN
            SELECT NULL AS DB_Name,* 
            INTO ##output
            FROM authentication WHERE 1=0
         END

     INSERT INTO ##output
     Select '''+ @DB_Name + ''' ,'+

 --Enter query below
 '* from authentication where username like ''%clair@indicater%'' and password = ''Rohan2410'''

 --  print @Command
 EXEC sp_executesql @Command


 FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 
END

CLOSE database_cursor 
DEALLOCATE database_cursor

SELECT * FROM ##output

DROP TABLE ##output
```

Basically, on the first cursor iteration we will create an empty temp table with the correct structure. Then we just insert into that temp table.